# How would you use trimstart in vb.net for the following?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to remove the leading zeros/"0" to set a planes heading and pitch but how would I go about it? In the first few attempts I have converted the integer values to string values using the `CInt` function and converting it back to an integer however this just turn up errors. Can anybody help? thanks in advance.

```
     Dim pitchint As Integer
    pitchint = Pitch_txt.Text
    If pitchint > 720 Then
        pitchint = pitchint - 720
        Pitch_txt.Text = pitchint
    Else
        If pitchint > 360 Then
            pitchint = pitchint - 360
            Pitch_txt.Text = pitchint
        End If
    End If

    If Pitch_txt.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        If Pitchlbl.Text <> Pitch_txt.Text Then
            Pitchlbl.Text = Pitch_txt.Text
        End If
    End If
```

the following is what i would do if i wanted to put pitchint to a string then back to integer

```
Dim pitchint As String
    pitchint = Pitch_txt.Text
    pitchint = CInt(pitchint.TrimStart("0"))
    If pitchint > 720 Then
        pitchint = pitchint - 720
        Pitch_txt.Text = pitchint
    Else
        If pitchint > 360 Then
            pitchint = pitchint - 360
            Pitch_txt.Text = pitchint
        End If
    End If

    If Pitch_txt.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        If Pitchlbl.Text <> Pitch_txt.Text Then
            Pitchlbl.Text = Pitch_txt.Text
        End If
    End If
```

there are no errors as such other than the value returned in the textbox and label are the same ie if i enter 070 the value returned is 070 no change.

Comment: Can you show with an example what you trying to achieve?

Comment: You want to remove the zeros from the pitchint integer?

Comment: What does `Pitch_txt.Text` actually contain? If you're getting errors with `CInt`, what errors? ("just turn up errors" is not a description of a problem unless you say what the errors are that you're getting.) If this is VB.NET, why aren't you using `Int32.TryParse` to do the conversion from string to integer?

Comment: Try Integer.Parse(inputString) in order to remove the leading zeroes: integer.Parse("000001200") - output is 1200

Comment: @pasty, Integar.Parse will throw an error if the value you are trying to parse is not a number. Integer.TryParse is a safer option.

Comment: so the value in the pitch_txt text box is put in pitchint for storage and transfer. the maxlength for pitch_txt is 3 so if i input 999 this will see that it is > 720 and take away 720 giving 279 this value is put back into the textbox and label for pitch. however if this value is 070 i want it to return 70 into the text box and label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with "070" is because you only process values >360 and NEVER assign Pitch_txt.text = pitchint at the end of your nested IF. is a loose end you having here

```
If pitchint > 720 Then
    pitchint = pitchint - 720
    Pitch_txt.Text = pitchint '<--Pitch_txt.Text was assigned
Else
    If pitchint > 360 Then
        pitchint = pitchint - 360
        Pitch_txt.Text = pitchint '<--Pitch_txt.Text was assigned
    End If

    'how about if pitchint=70?
    'Pitch_txt.text was not assign with pitchint integer value 70 and will remained as "070" (string)
End If
```

I rewrite your code to a neater version below:

```
    Dim pitchint As Integer
    pitchint = Val(Pitch_txt.Text) 'simple way will filter out trailing non-numerics input
    If pitchint > 720 Then
        pitchint -= 720
    ElseIf pitchint > 360 Then
        pitchint -= 360
    End If

    Pitch_txt.Text = pitchint '<--put this line here will solve your "070" issue

    If Pitch_txt.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        If Pitchlbl.Text <> Pitch_txt.Text Then
            Pitchlbl.Text = Pitch_txt.Text
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: @OliverHands remember to give me a 'tick' on my answer if solves your question :P